# Is it possible to "manually" open your Facebook messages, "programmatically"?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, debugging

Is it possible to "manually" open your Facebook message inbox in-browser, programmatically?

(i.e., via the "native" code/functions that Facebook normally uses to do it -- without using Facebook's API, and without an actual mouse click or Tab-Enter of the icon)

On Facebook, when you put the mouse over your message-inbox icon and click -- the inbox drops down.

Would it possible to capture programmatically what's actually happening when this is clicked, thus making the inbox drop down as if the icon had been clicked (like a debugger catching function calls)?

And if so, would it be possible to manually "replay" this programmatic pull of the puppet-strings that a mouse-click would pull, to emulate this click and see the ensuing drop-down of the inbox, -- again without using the API or any kind of physical or automated clicking/tab-entering?

This doesn't necessarily have to be done through an entirely self-contained program. If it's possible to do in-browser, like via Javascript (Scratchpad)/Greasemonkey (sans FB API) -- all the better.

Comment: I genuinely "love" the use of quotes in this question.

Comment: Employees "must" wash hands...

Comment: "Good" points. Editing :D

Comment: Possibly something http://seleniumhq.org/ could do...

Comment: Perhaps I'd be better asking -- What's happening programmatically when a user normally clicks the inbox icon in Facebook? Is there some PHP code being run? Is there some sort of Javascript listener waiting to act? What/Where's the specific code being used or run to listen for this click and then make the message inbox appear?

Comment: In case you are looking for a way to backup your messages, you might be interested in tool I created for this https://github.com/agentcooper/facebook-inbox-backup

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do this with PHP.

Your best bet would be to use a browser automation tool that will record your actions and play them back. For example, but not necessarily, Selenium.

This will simulate the manual clicking of elements on the page, without using the Facebook API.

Comment: If the page has loaded and the code is all there -- would it not be possible to just "manually" emulate/pull the same puppet-strings that a mouse-click would push through?

Comment: That's exactly what Selenium does - by automating the browser. I'm not sure how you'd do this with PHP - if you loaded the page with PHP how would you render it and run any JavaScript, for example?

Comment: Selenium looks like a great tool, but it's still "physically" clicking, so to speak, by an abstraction layer, much like scripting AutoHotKey to move the mouse to a specific position and clicking.

I'm trying to do this without any abstraction layers, firing the page's native triggers/events manually, without any layer in-between -- and doing this all within the browser.

So perhaps I should be asking -- What is happening programmatically when a user normally clicks the inbox icon in Facebook? Is there some PHP code being run? Is there some sort of Javascript listener waiting to act?

Comment: I imagine there is a JavaScript event that makes an AJAX request to get the data from the server - fire up the browser dev tools to inspect the element / view the network traffic.